# .click() on element nested inside of element with .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an accordion inside of an accordion... and I am struggling a little.

essentially, I have a div `.applicant`, which upon click adds a class `.expand`, which sets the height to auto, but, inside of the `.applicant` div, I have another div `.applicant-child`, which SHOULD do the same thing, and does... but, `.applicant` closes when you click `.applicant-child`, meaning you have to click the `.applicant` again to open view the nested element.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="applicant">
                <p><b>PS4 Tournaments</b></p>
                <div class="applicant-child">
                    <p>lalal</p>
                    <p>lalal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('.applicant').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
            $(this).removeClass('expand');
        } else {
            $( this ).addClass('expand');
        }
    });

    $('.applicant-child').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
            $(this).removeClass('expand');
        } else {
            $( this ).addClass('expand');
        }
    });
```

I could simply remove `$(this).removeClass('expand');` from `.appliant`, but we'll be displaying a lot of data, so that isn't ideal.

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make `application` div and `application-child` div siblings. Nested clicks are bad idea

Comment: You need to call `stopPropagation()` on the `click` event that's raised. You can also simplify the class adding/removnig by just using `toggleClass()`

Comment: Cheers, @RoryMcCrossan. Wasn't aware of that. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just event bubbling an expected behaviour.
See this [link](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) on jQuery on how to disable the `click-Event` to bubble up the DOM and triggering the event on your parent element.

Basically, you just have to do this:

```
$('.applicant-child').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
        $(this).removeClass('expand');
    } else {
        $( this ).addClass('expand');
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  I wasn't aware of this, I am somewhat new to jQuery. Thank you very much, Agash! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent bubbling. Bubbling means, that the event you are reacting to is being passed up the DOM to the parent objects, until it reaches the window.

Check out the "event.stopPropagation()" method, which will prevent any subsequent listeners from reacting.

Comment: Thank you, Treffnon! exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

On your click handler if you pass through a param:

```
$('.applicant').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target);
    if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
        $(this).removeClass('expand');
    } else {
        $( this ).addClass('expand');
    }
});
```

you can use event.target to check if you are clicking on the parent or the child and decide on what action to take from there.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I have opted to go with the answer @agash has provided, but it's great to know this can be done in multiple ways. Thanks!